# Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

1. I tried `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub cache repair`,
3. changing and versions of the fluttertoast package, and by removing it too,
4. deleted the *android/.gradle* directory and rebuilt.

Nothing worked.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 4 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Parameter format not correct -
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-7.1.8\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast\fluttertoast\MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt: (45, 84): Unresolved reference: R
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-7.1.8\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast\fluttertoast\MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt: (70, 68): Unresolved reference: R
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-7.1.8\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast\fluttertoast\MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt: (85, 64): Unresolved reference: R
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Could you provide your code of MethodCallHandlerImpl?

Comment: try previous version 7.1.6

Comment: I am gettin the same error.  I tried rolling back to 7.1.6, invalidating caches, flutter clean... none solved the problem.  I know I installed an Android related update in Android Studio.  Maybe it was related to that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Updating the `compileSdkVersion` to `30` in my `app/build.gradle` solved it and allowed me to keep the latest gradle.

OLD ANSWER:

I'm not sure why, but I was able to resolve the problem by rolling back to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
```

in my top level `build.gradle`.

Comment: Gradle what? Gradle file? Gradle folder? Gradle configuration? Gradle installation? Something else? Please respond by answer, not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Worked after flutter clean

Comment: Worked for me after rolling back the build:gradle version

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'

Comment: recently i ran "flutter upgrade" then i faced similar issue. i tried all suggestions posted here but nothing worked. then i ran "flutter downgrade", "flutter clean", "flutter pub get", and the app worked fine.. seems there is issue with flutter new version?!